# WPF Binding to ElementName raises NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to validate some input data in WPF, and am using the DataResource proxy as described here:
http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-add-binding-to-property-on.html

So, here's my XAML (simplified):

```
<mvvm:BaseDataView
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:md="clr-namespace:Mfc.Mvvm.Master"
    >
<mvvm:BaseDataView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <md:DataResource x:Key="mmSS" BindingTarget="{Binding ElementName=tbMmss,Path=Text}"/>
        <md:DataResource x:Key="mmTS" BindingTarget="{Binding ElementName=tbMmts,Path=Text}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</mvvm:BaseDataView.Resources>
...
<TextBox x:Name="tbMmts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Margin="3,3,0,0">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="MTS" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <md:DoubleRangeValidationRule MinValue="10.0" MaxValue="5000.0"/>
                        <md:LessThanValidationRule>
                            <md:LessThanValidationRule.LessThanChecker>
                                <md:ProxyForComparisonString
                                    CompareTo="{md:DataResourceBinding DataResource={StaticResource mmSS}}">
                                </md:ProxyForComparisonString>
                            </md:LessThanValidationRule.LessThanChecker>
                        </md:LessThanValidationRule>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
...

<TextBox x:Name="tbMmss" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Margin="3,3,0,0">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="STS" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <md:DoubleRangeValidationRule MinValue="10.0" MaxValue="5000.0"/>
                        <md:GreaterThanValidationRule>
                            <md:GreaterThanValidationRule.GreaterThanChecker>
                                <md:ProxyForComparisonString
                                    CompareTo="{md:DataResourceBinding DataResource={StaticResource mmTS}}">
                                </md:ProxyForComparisonString>
                            </md:GreaterThanValidationRule.GreaterThanChecker>
                        </md:GreaterThanValidationRule>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

Validation works perfectly for the *second* textbox, but it crashes with a NullReferenceException for the *first* Textbox. The **DataResource** does not seem to get initialized, and Debugging says

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=tbMmss'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataResource'
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The tbMmts is at the path you specified?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. `tbMss` is the TextBox specified in the XAML, and the `Path=Text` refers to the `Text` Property of said TextBox.

Comment: Sry i was miss reading. At this line  `<md:DataResource x:Key="mmTS" BindingTarget="{Binding ElementName=tbMmts,Path=Text}"/>` are you binding to an object where text == "" or null

Comment: I am binding to the `TextBox` defined in the XAML I provided. The `Text` property is null on initiation, but is itself bound to `STS` as per the XAML - also, the binding is successful (ie. I see the value for STS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a completely wrong approach for this. Do not use Freezables. They are bad. They are not ment to be stuck in a resource and violated to deal like bridges!!! Please use attached properties or INotifyDataError info to solve this clean and properly.

Comment: I agree on the violation part - however, it does not solve the problem of *Validating against another value* - `ValidationRule` does not implement `DependencyObject`, so properties are right out, and they're not in the same logical tree (so they have no `FrameworkElement` parent you could bind to). Thank you anyways, I will investigate further!

Comment: Use two bindings in a MultiBinding on Text property with ValidationRule handling those two values. Then you have all you need

Comment: What I ended up doing was implementing a "double proxy" as described in http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-properties and http://michlg.wordpress.com/tag/validationrule/ :

Comment: Why not MultiBinding? Its clean and save and pure wpf.  Please make sure that all those proxy thingies free memory properly.